# Windows Phone 7 access to Share Picker

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to access the Share Picker in my application? I have read about making my own Share Picker Extension, but that isn't really what I am looking for. I want the user to be able to share a generated image from my app.

Thank you,
Doc Haven

Comment: you mean this one? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967563%28VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: No. I am wanting to be able to open up the picker from my application, as opposed to opening it from the Pictures app, so that the user can share it with what ever other extensions, like what you have linked, that they want to use. Please correct though me if I did miss something in on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The SharePicker allows you to add functionality from your application to the Pictures Hub.
There is no way to add that functionality, from the hub, back into your app.

If you want to be able to "share" something with the web (e.g. sent do Facebook/Twitter) then you must implement this yourself.
There is no way to link between your application and another on the device.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I feared, but it is understandable from a security standpoint.